# Image caching in circleCi

Tags: docker, circleci

I wonder that is the difference between `pull stats: Image was already available so the image was not pulled` and `image cache not found on this host, downloading cimg/node:14.17.6` below?

When I read at circleCI website they say that next gen images will have *"and a higher likelihood that the image is already cached on the host."* ([next gen images on circleCi](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/)).

But first the image is `available` on the host and later on it is `downloaded` because `cache not found`?

Best Regards

[image]